# Get the second child of a jQuery element

Tags: jquery, html, this, element

This question might be duplicated, but I haven't found anything helpful.

Here's my snippet:

```js
$("table tbody tr").hover(

  function() {
    var secondCell = $(this).children[1].textContent;

    //secondCell.someCode
  },

  function() {
    //some code
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>foo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All I wanna do is: When a player hovers a row, it should alert them a message and that message has the second cell text.
Hope you get the idea, and thanks in advance.

Comment: $( "tr td:nth-child(2)" ) that should make it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jquery, `.children()` is a *function*. So you need to call it before you can get an element out of the array. Have a look at the [jquery .children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) documentation.

You can use it like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6v1Lqyc/).

Comment: Oh yeah, I saw this one, but when I typed it my IDE said that `children` isn't a function, it's an array, but when I tried it it worked.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways:

`$( "tr td:nth-child(2)" )`

`$( "tr").children().eq(1)`

`$( "tr td").eq(1)`

`$( "tr td").filter(":nth-child(2)")`

Comment: Thank you habibi, but you know, I wanna get the cell of the row that's already selected, using $(this), thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code also

```
$("table tbody tr").hover(

    function() {
        var secondCell = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();

        //secondCell.someCode
    },

    function() {
        //some code
    }

);
```